# Wooden siding repair

Tags: repair, siding

I have some timber siding (planks of wood) that over lap. I've been told its shiplap but according to the place I got my wood the wood is shiplap but the style of overlaying it is something else.

Anyway, you know what I have, my question is how do I remove a rotten piece that when the house was built had a exterior porch added on later so now most of the wood is inside the house and some of its out side.

I assume that you lift the planks above to remove it but how do I cut out the bad part with out causing further damage?

Comment: A photograph would go a long way here.  Short answer is using a sawzall with a piece of sheet metal slid up behind.

Comment: A sawzall! The one item my father-in-law didn't own. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: For just a few cuts you could block behind the cut with 3/4" stock, then use a skillsaw to cut as much as possible, then take out the blocking and slid in the sheet metal, then finish the cut by hand using a key-hole saw with the blade mounted upside down.

Comment: A sawzall will go right through the sheet metal, too. ;) I'd consider a small radial saw set to the depth of the siding or an oscillating saw.

Comment: @DA01 - Good point. If you are worried that you can't tell through feel or sound the difference between cutting through sheet metal and cutting through wood, use a blade that is designed exclusively for cutting wood.  That is, do not use a blade designed to cut through nails.